# Blender 2.79 not working in Windows Server 2019 on AWS cloud t2.micro

Tags: windows, installation

I was trying to install Blender 2.79 on Windows Server 2019 on [AWS cloud t2.micro](https://www.quora.com/What-is-T2-instances). It installs but does not start - neither GUI, nor by using  `blener -b` command. The error it gives says `does not have display driver or OpenGL`. But this version ran in my laptop without graphics card. What should I do?

Comment: Your laptop most certainly had a graphics card, although likely one integrated in the CPU. Otherwise it would not have been able to display any graphics at all.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a graphics card. Blender does not and did never support to run at the onboard graphics of the cpu. Even when it works in some cases.

Comment: While a GPU is required for running Blender, it is incorrect that Blender does not support integrated GPUs. Intel CPUs Haswell and newer are officially supported with their integrated GPUs, although they do not allow GPU accelerated rendering with Cycles. The requirements for running Blender can be found here: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Thanks for the correction Robert, but isn't that for Blender 3? He runs Blender 2.79. And even here, still just a fraction of integrated gpu is supported.

Comment: Blender 2.79 has lower hardware requirements, thus it should work on more hardware, including older integrated GPUs such as the Intel HD Graphics 4000. The issue here is that the AWS instance likely does not have any GPU nor OpenGL software emulation and thus it does not fulfill the minimum requirements for running Blender.